# Selenium python how do I wait for for an elements to be created

Tags: python, selenium

On page I have table export list element which changes after a few seconds to few minutes (Pending, Processing and Completed) or either the progress bar is at 100% completion.
From:

```
<p id="2c92c0f953cfa2d80153e8409eggFeb9" class="ares_txt15">  Pending  </p> </td>
```

To:

```
<p id="22c92c0f953cfa2d80153e6404bcc12c2" class="ares_txt15">  Completed                                                          
<script type="text/javascript"> var newPro0 = new ProgressBar('100'-0).appendTo('2c92c08653cf9ce60153e6cde69d57da'); </script>
<div class="iblock" style="vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 5px;">
<div class="iblock" style="width: 80px; height: 8px; border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); padding: 1px; font-size: 0px; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 0px;">
<div class="iblock" style="width: 80px; height: 8px; background: rgb(115, 194, 56) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;"/>
</div>
<span class="iblock" style="padding: 0px 5px; line-height: 11px; vertical-align: middle;">100%</span>
</div>
</p
```

This is what I had:

```
 >>> all_data = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='ares_txt15']")
    >>> for row in all_data:
        print(row.text)

    Pending
    Completed 100%
    Completed 100%
    Completed 100%
    Completed 100%
    Completed 100%

        try:
            WebDriverWait(browser, 80).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="ares_text15" and contains(text(), "Completed 100%")]')))
        except TimeoutException:
            raise Exception('Unable to find text in this element after waiting 80 seconds')



        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<pyshell#56>", line 4, in <module>
            raise Exception('Unable to find text in this element after waiting 80 seconds')
        Exception: Unable to find text in this element after waiting 80 seconds
```

Comment: Raise the time to 10 sec to 60 . see if it will work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()=="Completed"` should be `text()="Completed"` with one `=`

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="ares_text15" and text()="Completed"]')))
```

You can also try `contains` instead of `=`

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="ares_text15" and contains(text(), "Completed")]')))
```

You can also try to use `text_to_be_present_in_element`

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ares_text15'), 'Completed'))
```

Comment: i tried your suggested code above. still getting that timeout exception. could you please see above

Comment: @RicardLe I added another solution